# how to see when a client-coming socket is created of the server

Tags: c, linux, sockets, linux-kernel, server

```
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Mar 10 21:52 83 -> socket:[3357715842]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Mar 10 21:52 84 -> socket:[3357717636]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Mar 10 21:52 85 -> socket:[3357718699]
```

above is the result of "ls -al /proc/8108/fd/".
is the time the create time or the recent r/w time?

Comment: Surely you can tell that yourself by observation? If the time doesn't change, it's creation time.

Comment: thx~ The num 3357715842 in "socket:[3357715842]" means what? Is it inode num? Futher more, if a new connection come and reuse a conn's fd   which is just closed(but inode changes),should the create time change(i think so)? My question come from—— when i take 'ls -al /proc/8108/fd/',i see some connection whose time is long  ago,but when try tcpdump:no data exchanging! BUT TOME ,if new conn use diff inode,the create time should change! I am confused~